# How to sort a table of custom posts by column containing custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, sort

I have a custom post type called `laptop` with custom fields such as `CPU`, `OS`, `RAM` etc. creatied using the `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin.

I'm displaying a table of laptops, where the table header is a row of custom fields, and each following row is a laptop name and it's custom field values in each of the corresponding column cells.

I want to be able to sort the table by clicking on the table `TH` cell containing the custom field name.

I've been pointed to [meta query clauses](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) by ACF support, but I'm out of my depth with those.

I'd really appreciate some help in generating URLs to wrap around the the custom field name in each `TH` element.

Comment: can this help you a bit http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183601/sorting-posts-by-custom-field

Comment: @prosti, sort of. I don't have categories of laptops, and the custom post type `laptop` is not a category of Wordpress post. Also, I need to be able to filter by multiple custom fields, not just one, and I don't see from the code in the answer above how to do that. Thanks though!

Comment: can this help you https://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Comment: Thanks @prosti, that's a great resource, however, it does not allow you to specify that you want to order the results by custom field, which is what I need.

Comment: have you managed to sort things out ?

Comment: Am I correct to assume you are planning to do sorting via back-end request? And if Yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on @rock3t's comment, do you really have to query the backend whenever a user clicks on a column header?

Have you looking into using the jQuery [tablesorter](https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/)?  It allows an end-user to sort an HTML table by doing DOM manipulations.

I've never used it in a WP project, but I have used it extensively in other projects I've built and it works great.  It's **very** configurable, so I'm sure it will satisfy your needs.

tablesorter is **not** one of the jQuery plugins included with WP Core.  So you'll have to download it (from the above link), include it in your plugin/theme somewhere and enqueue it.  Then, enqueue a simple JS file that would like something like:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready (function () {         
        $('#id_of_your_table').tablesorter ({widgets: ['zebra']}) ;     
        }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```

You can read more about how to use tablesort in their [docs](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), including various other parms to the `tablesorter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple with this reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

orderby should be `meta_value`

> 'meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in the query.

Your key name should be one of the: CPU, OS, RAM ...

Also you can consider the `WP_Meta_Query` class.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

---

### The Update

---

I got this result

```
    Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3233
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2016-11-19 12:51:43
            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-11-19 12:51:43
            [post_content] => abc
            [post_title] => Mac Air Pro 9G
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => mac-air-pro-3
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2016-11-19 12:52:19
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-11-19 12:52:19
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://steve.com/laptop/mac-air-pro-1-copy/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => laptop
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3232
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2016-11-19 12:46:50
            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-11-19 12:46:50
            [post_content] => abc
            [post_title] => Mac Air Pro 8G
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => mac-air-pro-2
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2016-11-19 12:52:47
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-11-19 12:52:47
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://steve.com/laptop/mac-air-pro-1-copy/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => laptop
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3231
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2016-11-19 12:12:38
            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-11-19 12:12:38
            [post_content] => abc
            [post_title] => Mac Air Pro 4G
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => mac-air-pro-1
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2016-11-19 12:52:57
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-11-19 12:52:57
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://steve.com/?post_type=laptop&#038;p=3231
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => laptop
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

Here is the content of the single-laptop.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package microformats
 */

get_header(); 


// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'laptop' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'published' ),
     //'s'                      => 'atom', // only if you need that
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true,
    // order
    'orderby'                => 'meta_value', 
    'meta_key'               => 'ram',
    'order'                  =>'DESC',
    /* you will need this only if
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'ram', // or os, or cpu
            'value'     => '4', // meaning 4G of ram
            'compare'   => '>',  // meaning only biggar
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
    */
);


// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
print_r($query->posts);


?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' ); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>


            <hr class="fat" />              

        <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you prosti. By default, I want all `laptops` to display, so I have: `$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'laptop', 'postsperpage' => '30', 'max_num_pages' => 20 ) );`. I don't want to limit the default `WP_Query` by `meta_value`. How would I use your solution given this requirement for a default set of laptops? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, OK, I am working on something extremely important, so I don't have even 10 minutes right now. However, I will update you in next few days.

Comment: Hi @prosti, how are things going?

Comment: Check it @Steve.

Comment: Hi Prosti, that did not help. It is not single-laptop.php I need help with, but the front-page.php which produces the table of laptops.

Comment: Try to replace:`'orderby' => 'meta_value'` at `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`